# Why doesn't h:dataTable inside ui:repeat get correct ID?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Code:

```
<ui:repeat var="obj" value="#{demo2Bean.someList}">
    <h:panelGroup id="foo" />
    <h:dataTable id="bar" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Result:

```
<span id="j_idt55:0:foo"></span>
<table id="j_idt55:0:bar"><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
<span id="j_idt55:1:foo"></span>
<table id="j_idt55:0:bar"><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

As you can see, the id for datatables is the same 'j_idt55:0:bar' but for panelGroups it grows (as should): 'j_idt55:0:foo', 'j_idt55:1:foo'. Why is it so?

Comment: might be a bug. Try upgrading to the latest releasy

Comment: Running Mojarra 2.0.2, I actually bumped into a possible (blocker) bug with Mojarra 2.0.3 (https://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1825). Guess I should try this with a clean project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's a bug in [`UIData#getClientId()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#getClientId%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29). I've reported it as [issue 1830](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1830).

Comment: Cool, thanks for inspecting and reporting it. It occurs already with Mojarra 2.0.2, so maybe change that to the ticket.

Comment: The version is just the max version wherein the occurrence is confirmed.

Comment: It is fixed in 2.1.12, and 2.2.0-m06.