# JSF / Mojarra 2.0.2: ui:repeat is totally broken when updating via AJAX

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

Using `ui:repeat` for simple listing of elements produces very strange results - when you add an element, the first element is always replaced with the values from the last element *before* the submit. Same occurs when removing the elements - the first element shows actually the just removed element.

With `h:dataTable` the same works perfectly.

Running Mojarra 2.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because [bug in Mojarra 2.0.2](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1830). At least in this case, updating to Mojarra 2.0.3 resolves the issue. However, the bug refers to cases that won't work with even 2.0.3.

Just wanted to write this up into a separate question as I've been having all sorts of problems (and asking all sort of questions) relating to `ui:repeat` and this is a specific case again.

Other failings with `ui:repeat`:

- [Why doesn't h:dataTable inside ui:repeat get correct ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880993/why-doesnt-hdatatable-inside-uirepeat-get-correct-id)
- [How to refer to dataTable parent within the dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882147/how-to-refer-to-datatable-parent-within-the-datatable)

My conclusion: the whole `ui:repeat` tag is totally broken at least in Mojarra 2.0.2. Updating to Mojarra 2.0.3 fixes some of the issues.