# ui: repeat not working with a p: datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I just read the related question
[why-doesnt-hdatatable-inside-uirepeat-get-correct-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880993/why-doesnt-hdatatable-inside-uirepeat-get-correct-id)

I have a list of PrimeFaces datatable on my bean, and I want to use ui:repeat to cycle through all these tables.. However the iteration is not working..

Any ideas?

My relevant piece of code is the following:

```
<ui:repeat id="searchTables"
                   value="#{searchBean.resultList}"
                   var="currentListOfLists">
            <p:dataTable id="bindedTable"
                         binding="#{currentListOfLists}"
                         var="currentList"/>
        </ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataTable does not have a value which the iteration is to be done on.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{currentListOfLists}" var="currentList">
```

The binding attribute is used to link the dataTable to a property in a backing bean.

Comment: Mark, thanks for your observation. Even though it didn't actually solve my problem (As the the lists are not being shown on the DataTables, its a good start point to have this clear :)